# How can I counter the Chirrut and Baze ("Chaze") combo?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

When Chirrut and Baze are on the same team, it seems like I can never kill either of them. Chirrut heals too much and does too much damage, and Baze is so tanky it feels like he can't die. I've tried using characters that apply Buff Block to either of the two characters, but apparently Chirrut has a cleanse too! What is the counterplay to this combination of characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option that I use is a Sith team lead by Darth Vader with a Zeta'd leadership ability.  The others I use are Nihilus, Emperor Palpatine, Darth Maul, and Count Dooku, but it can definitely work with other characters too (I used to use Royal Guard in place of Maul).

All Sith/Empire attacks have a good chance to remove Turn Meter from opponents under Vader, which is especially useful since 4 of those 5 have AoE attacks and can prevent the enemy team from moving for several turns at times (giving you time to wear down Baze).  In addition:

- Count Dooku's basic often double-attacks to remove more Turn Meter, with a chance to stun, and his special has a high chance to stun two opponents.
- Nihilus applies a DoT at the start of each of his turns which makes Vader's second special attack more powerful.  His basic cleanses buffs, eliminating Baze's taunt and/or Retribution and/or Chirrut's HoTs.  Most importantly, his first special increases ability cooldowns, preventing Baze from taunting and Chirrut from cleansing (as well as preventing the rest of the team from using their best abilities).  His second special will come off cooldown fairly quickly with how often you can use the first one against this combo, which means that you can one-shot kill either of them or another threat.
- Darth Maul's special gives a debuff that will prevent Baze from counter-attacking, even when he has the Retribution buff.
- Darth Vader's basic ability blocks and prevents the taunts/cleanses.
- Emperor Palpatine has an AoE stun and his basic applies a debuff that blocks buffs, useful against letting Baze gain taunts/Retribution/HoTs while Chirrut is unable to cleanse (but it's more important not to let them take turns in the first place).

Comment: Something I found that helps but is not enough for it's own answer, is to focus on the other three heroes with Baze and Chirrut. Too many people get wound up in trying to take them down first they're not dealing with the other three heroes doing damage. Baze and Chirrut have great synergy together but lack great synergy with other team members (beyond the Cleanse).

Comment: In continuation of my previous comment, Chirrut is at his most powerful when he has 4 allies so that his special does extra damage. Taking down the other three will reduce the potential power of his most damaging move. All of Baze's attacks are relatively weak unless you have Empire squads or no way to buff your party.

Comment: I keep coming back to this question as I get more experience with the game. I would say Nihilus is almost pivotal for taking down a good Chaze team. Chirrut and Baze are so tanky with the health steal and counter chance that a lot of game I lost not because my heroes died, but because I couldn't kill them before running out of time. Nihilus is a no-if-no-buts OHKO, and once one of them is dead the other topples easily. It's also worth saying you need to play on 4x speed to have as much time as possible to beat them.

Comment: Also to add my input, ever since I got thrawn, I haven't had a problem. Being able to fracture one of these characters makes it much easier to deal with

Answer (score 3):

Grand Admiral Thrawn is also an effective counter to Chaze when you are the one attacking. His Fracture Ability removes any existing debuffs, prevents them for gaining new ones, and effectively blocks the following abilities for Baze:

- For Jedha
- Indomitable Will
- Resolute Endurance

This means that you can either attack Chirrut without fear of triggering Baze's taunt, or focus down Baze without worrying about him healing under Chirrut.

The Resistance faction is also strong against any team when being used offensively, provided you have Finn's Leader ability "Zeta'd" (Upgraded to level 8, which requires 20 Zeta Materials).

Without going to much into how Resistance works (as it is complicated), Finn's Special Ability can Stun enemies, as can R2's Basic Ability. Simply place a stun on Baze/Chirrut to prevent counter-attacks, then use Resistance Trooper's special to remove the Taunt on Baze. Coupled with the Turn Meter Reduction from Poe's Special and Turn Meter gain from Finn's Leader ability when hitting Exposed targets, Baze and Chirrut should never even take a turn.

Either place Buff Immunity on Baze with Poe's Special ability or kill Baze first to prevent his Taunt coming back from taking Chirrut below 100% Health.